# Datastore "no such struct field"

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to fetch data from my Datastore database, I hit a wall and can't seem to get any further...

What works:

```
    type Foo struct {
        X int `json:"x" datastore:"first"`
        Y int `json:"y" datastore:"second"`
        Z int `json:"z" datastore:"third"`
    }
```

What I want:

```
type Foo struct {
    X int `json:"x" datastore:"first"
    Y int `json:"y" datastore:"second"`
    Bar []Bars `json:"more"`
}

type Bars struct {
    Z int `json:"z" datastore:"third"`
}
```

I'm getting the error `datastore: Cannot load field "third" into "main.Foo": no such struct field.`

Can anyone help?